How to render the content of a component which is under component collection of component collection
How to render the data in my maincontainer.cshtml for the third level "Component" at the bottom mentioned from the below model and schema desing?
component = Model.Items.Where(c => c.Title?.Key?.FormatUrl() == "test")?.Select(x => x.Data).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();

[ContentModel("Component", true, ViewModelKeys = new string[] {"component"})]
public class Component : ViewModelBase, IRenderableViewModel

I have a component Named "MainContainer" with a model contains the below schema design
[ContentModel("Container", true, ViewModelKeys = new string[] { "container" })]
public class Container: ViewModelBase, IRenderableViewModel
{
    [TextField(FieldName = "IntroText")]
    public string IntroText { get; set; }

    [LinkedComponentField(FieldName = "Items")]
    public List<ComponentCollection> Items { get; set; }

    [RenderData]
    public IRenderData RenderData { get; set; }

}

For the component collection Named "ComponentCollection" with a model contains the below schema design
[ContentModel("ComponentCollection", true, ViewModelKeys = new string[] { "componentcollection" })]
public class ComponentCollection : ViewModelBase, IRenderableViewModel
{
    [TextField(FieldName = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [LinkedComponentField(FieldName = "Data")]
    public List<Component> Data { get; set; }

    [RenderData]
    public IRenderData RenderData { get; set; }
}

For the component above Named "Component" with a model contains the below schema design
[ContentModel("Component", true, ViewModelKeys = new string[] {"component"})]
public class Component : ViewModelBase, IRenderableViewModel
{
    [TextField(FieldName = "Question")]
    public string Question { get; set; }

    [RichTextField(FieldName = "Answer")]
    public MvcHtmlString Answer { get; set; }

    [TextField(FieldName = "IsQnAStructure")]
    public string IsQnAStructure { get; set; }

    [TextField(FieldName = "FurtherAssistance")]
    public string FurtherAssistance { get; set; }

    [RenderData]
    public IRenderData RenderData { get; set; }
}


The DD4T libraries in your web application will follow component links to any level. The limiting factor is on the template side. By default, the templates will follow component links to one level deep. So if a links to b links to c, only a and b are part of the published (json) data. However, you can increase the depth by adding a parameter called LinkLevels to your templates. If you would set it to 2, component c would be included in the data.
One caveat: don't set the LinkLevels higher than needed. The data will grow exponentially and may become too big. A value of 2 or even 3 is normally not a problem though.

Thank you very much @Quirjin for your clarification. Anyhow I have rendered the components based on the schema id from config file and displyed it. Sorry for late reply and response.!!! :)
